# need to load one record from a json

Tags: extjs, store

After i click on a row in the grid i want to be able to load one record from a json. So when i click on a row i do this:

```
listeners: {
        itemclick: function () {
            var data = grid.getSelectionModel().selected.items[0].data;
        }
    }
```

so now i know the id

```
data.justusId
```

But how do i load the store with only that id? The json is this

```
{"justus":[{
      "justusId":"yippie",
      "toys":{"location":"u-13","status":"empty","minStock":10}},
{
      "justusId":"cowboy",
      "toys":{"location":"u-11","status":"full","minStock":10}},
{
      "justusId":"car",
      "toys":{"location":"l-32","status":"aler","minStock":10}}]
```

So when i click on the row cowboy i want to be able to load a store with that item

Answer (score 0):

A store is used typically for managing a collection of items, not just a single record.

In ExtJS4, you'd use the Model.load() functionality.

In previous versions, you'd typically just use the standard Ext.Ajax.Request() call.

Comment: but how do i load just one record from the json?